# Sharing the Quill toolbar between multiple editor instances

Tags: quill

I'm using Quill in a single page application with a fixed toolbar at the bottom of the screen. The application dynamically creates new Quill editor instances on the fly (sometimes with multiple editors onscreen, side by side, at the same time).

I'd like those editors to all share the same toolbar instance, and if there are multiple editors onscreen simultaneously, it should send its commands only to the focused instance. Is this possible?

Someone else has [already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441303/share-quill-toolbar-across-multiple-editors) on StackOverflow, but their question is almost two years old and it hasn't been answered.

Right now, I'm building my own custom toolbar (not managed by Quill at all) and writing my own custom code to delegate commands into the appropriate Quill instance. But it feels like I'm duplicating a lot of default Quill functionality, and I'd like to consolidate if possible.

Comment: There is an open feature request for this: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/633. I don't personally have the need so am not qualified to design the solution (ex. what do the APIs for attaching/detaching look like) but if you can add your thoughts perhaps there can be movement.

Comment: Thanks! I commented on the github issue, and I'd be happy to answer any questions you might have, in order to better understand this use case :)